# Is it possible to create a LL parser using BNF grammar?

Tags: parsing, grammar, bnf, ll-grammar

I looked on google for know if it was possible to create an LL parser using a BNF grammar but I saw on wikipedia that they use something like

```
S → F
S → ( S + F )
F → a
```

which is not a BNF grammar. Is it possible to use BNF grammar for create an LL parser or you have to use only LL grammar ?

Thank's

Comment: Yes, that is absolutely possible. BNF is just one of several specification formats that you can use - it's more a matter of personal preference, really.

Comment: Have you a tutorial to advise me for create an LL parser using BNF grammar ?
didn't find on google :/
Thx

Comment: Alas, I do not. If you have a specific grammar example in non-BNF that you can't figure out how to convert, post a question about that here and someone will most likely be able to help out.

Comment: I'm currently trying to re-code a part of a terminal shell and I already have the BNF grammar. Otherwise, I'm looking for a tutorial which explain how to create LL parser using BNF grammar

Comment: How much do you know about LL parsing? Are you familiar with FIRST and FOLLOW sets?

Comment: Not a lot about LL parsing. I just know that there's terminal and non-terminal characters and the parser lookahead. the LL parsing will provide me a binary tree which will be recursive...
That's all :/. I don't find a lot of doc on internet

Comment: This is typically something you'd spend a few days learning about in a compilers course. I taught a compilers class two years ago and have some slides on this. Check out the slide decks on top-down parsing: http://www.stanford.edu/class/archive/cs/cs143/cs143.1128/

Comment: Thank's for you link. But is it better for me to read a lot how a compilers work for learn about LL parser ? thx

Comment: While it's true that the example grammar (from Wikipedia) does not use the original BNF notation, it would be trivial to rewrite it. If you find instructions for how to create an LL parser from a context-free grammar, the particular notation used for the grammar shouldn't make that much difference. Are you sure that the grammar you have is in BNF, not some flavour of EBNF perhaps?

Comment: yes, I have a BNF grammar

http://my.safaribooksonline.com/book/operating-systems-and-server-administration/unix/1565923472/syntax/lbs.appd.div.3

Comment: that grammar is not LL. you should try an LR parser generator to build the parser.

Comment: Why should I try an LR parser ?
The LR parser is more adapt for this kind of grammar ?

Comment: @S7_0 because I don't think an LL parser generator will be able to handle that grammar as is (left recursive, ambiguous). at first sight I think you may have better luck with an LR parser generator, defining precedence and associativities (to solve the ambiguities) with the grammar unchanged.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. BNF is just a notation to represent context free grammars. Roughly ::= is the arrow, a `<symbol>` that appears to the left is a non-terminal and "literals" are terminal symbols (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backus%E2%80%93Naur_Form))

Take into account that not all context-free grammars are LL(1), there are grammars that have no LL parser.

If you use a parser generator you'll find out fast wether your grammar is LL or not. But if it isn't it may be difficult to correct it (especially if you have no background in language theory).